# Do the wandering trader's llamas despawn if I kill the wandering trader?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Let's say I push the [wandering trader](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wandering_Trader) into a 2 block deep hole and suffocate him with gravel for free leads. **Will his llamas despawn?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are not given a nametag (see [the wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Name_Tag#Behavior)), the llamas will act like normal mobs and despawn when the player is 128 blocks away from them.

Comment: tl:dr: Yes, as they act like normal mobs.